# Magento 2 - Changing Default Search Query Behavior

Tags: magento2, search, search-criteria

I have the following search criteria:

```
/?free_from%5B%5D=265&free_from%5B%5D=266
```

I'm trying to query all products and return ONLY products with both options A and B selected for the custom attribute **free_from**.

Currently with the above search criteria, A and B for example, i get search results for products where **EITHER A or B is assigned**.

I only want to return results where **BOTH A and B** are selected.

Is this possible? I'm assuming i would need to tap into the internal logic for querying products. Or should i simply change the search query in some way?

Thanks

Comment: did you find any solution? I am also facing the same issue.